# how to download a private google spreadsheet from linux command-line?

Tags: wget, authentication, google-drive

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet associated to a Google account, which is private and cannot be made public. I would like to know how to download a private google spreadsheet from the command-line of a Linux terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28494469/5848185

Comment: This only works for a sheet with a published URL

Answer (score 1):

It takes a bit of work to set up `rclone`. However, after you go through this trouble you can carry out a lot of Google Drive tasks using it from the command line.

In particular, the `--drive-shared-with-me` flag allows you to access files and folders that are in the Drive that are shared with the associated Google ID. Thus

```
rclone copy --drive-shared-with-me chosen_drive_name:location/spreadsheet destdir/
```

will copy over the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

[Watermint Toolbox](https://github.com/watermint/toolbox/) does this easily. It allows you to go through the OAuth login process to Google and then you can download the sheet data in several formats.

In the example below, I use it to export the sheet called "Sheet1" from a certain Google Sheets file. This results in multiple lines of output, each of which is a valid JSON object representing a table row. Then I can pipe the output to [`jq(1)`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and the resulting output will be a (pretty-printed) JSON object that is an array of the rows in the sheet.

```
./tbx services google sheets sheet export -id afw434gghyruyjkTxjcw3HIQj12tgwrDSF39JlXsg4_0 -range Sheet1 -output json | jq --slurp .
```

Comment: Please add a working demo on how to do using the tool

Comment: @annahri Good idea, I've added an example.